# Problems installing snap and heroku on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, snap, heroku

I am having some problems installing heroku on raspbian stretch lite.

Snap seems to install ok using the command `apt-get install snapd` as recommend in the install instructions on their website for raspbian. Some additional packages are installed such as.

`The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor libapparmor-perl snap-confine snapd squashfs-tools
  ubuntu-core-launcher`

This is the output from `snap version` once install has completed.

`snap      2.21-2
snapd     2.21-2
series    16
raspbian  9`

On another system where snap is also installed there is a 5th line that starts with kernel, this seems to be missing on the raspbian install of snap, unsure if that is of any relevance.

For the install of Heroku as there are no install instructions for `raspbian` I am following the Ubuntu 16+ instructions, albeit the instructions are only 1 step and this is to run the command of `sudo snap install --classic heroku`.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

The end result of running the install heroku command is that it fails, and somehow also breaks the snap install, it does look like it's working in that it downloads ok, and then takes a long time so appears to be installing, but then the error below is shown.

`error: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/changes/1: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused`

Once I have got to this stage running any snap commands such as `snap --version` shows the message `Illegal instruction`.

Answer (score 0):

Installing snaps/binaries intended for the x86/Intel compatible arquitecture in the a machine with the arm processor arquitecture won't work.

Pay more attention to that error : illegal instruction.

I would advise not trying to install Intel Ubuntu snaps in raspbian.